# Retrieve multiple images from MySql database via Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, php, mysql

We could say that we are beginners, We can consult and show our data (text) from Mysql but the images don´t show in Unity. Need some help! We hace tried almost everything! We can someone help us.

in C# we have...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using UnityEditor.Sprites;
public class Detalles : MonoBehaviour {

string url = "https://cdn.designrulz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/unique-house-garden-at-Luxury-and-Stylish-Glass-House-desgnrulz-3.jpg";
Texture2D img;


public string[] items;

public int num ;
public Image imagen;
public Text precio;
public Text tipo;
public Text superficie;
public Text recamaras;
public Text baños;
public Text cocheras;
public Text ciudad;
public Text ubicacion;

//
IEnumerator Start(){
    WWW itemsData = new WWW ("http://localhost/Casas/ItemsData2.php");
    yield return itemsData;
    string itemsDataString = itemsData.text;
    //print (itemsDataString);
    items = itemsDataString.Split (';');
    //num = items.Length - 1;
    //for( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ){
    //  }
    precio.text = " $ "+ GetDataValue (items[num],"Precio");
    tipo.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Tipo");
    superficie.text = " "+ GetDataValue (items[num],"Superficie")+" m2";
    recamaras.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Recamaras")+ " Recamaras";
    baños.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Sanitarios")+" Baños";
    cocheras.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Cocheras")+" Cocheras";
    ciudad.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Ciudad");
    ubicacion.text = " " + GetDataValue (items [num], "Ubicacion");
    StartCoroutine (LoadImg ());
}

IEnumerator LoadImg(){
    yield return 0;
    WWW imgLink = new WWW (url);
    yield return imgLink;
    img = imgLink.texture;
}

void Update(){
    imagen.sprite =  Sprite.Create (img, new Rect(0,0,690,345),new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
}

string GetDataValue(string data, string index){
    string value = data.Substring (data.IndexOf (index) + index.Length);
    value = value.Remove (value.IndexOf ("|"));
    return value;
```

In PHP we have...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "casas";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);


if(!$conn){
    die("Conection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id,titulo,foto,tipo,precio,superficie,sanitarios,recamaras,cocheras,colonia,ciudad,ubicacion FROM casas ORDER BY id ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Id".$row['id'] ."|Titulo".$row['titulo']."|Tipo".$row['tipo']."|Precio".$row['precio'] ."|Superficie".$row['superficie']."|Sanitarios".$row['sanitarios'] ."|Recamaras".$row['recamaras']."|Cocheras".$row['cocheras'] ."|Colonia".$row['colonia']."|Ciudad".$row['ciudad'] ."|Ubicacion".$row['ubicacion']."|".";";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should move the line

```
imagen.sprite =  Sprite.Create (img, new Rect(0,0,690,345),new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

from `Update()` to the end of `LoadImg()` as you don't want to be creating a new sprite every time the game updates.

Your code looks mostly ok otherwise. Here's a working code sample which loads an image from a URL. If it still doesn't work, comparing the two and modifying yours to match should fix the issue. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1175862/loading-a-sprite-from-url-c.html